# Surface of revolution is a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Given
$$\alpha : I \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,  \  \ \ \alpha(t)=(\alpha_1(t),\alpha_2(t)) \text.$$
It is a regular space and also homomorphic and $\alpha_2(t)>0$ for all $t \in I$.

Let $S$ be the surface in $x$-$y$-$z$-space provided by the rotating the curve
$$\{(x ,y ,0 ) \mid x =\alpha_1(t) ,\ y=\alpha_2(t),\ t\in I \}$$
around the $x$-axis.

How can I prove that $S$ is a regular surface?

All these symbols just got me confused. If you help me to solve this I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: What is your definition of regular surface?

Comment: And it is not clear what does "It is a regular space and also homomorphic" mean.

Comment: @ArcticChar I got the same textbook definition.Still, I could not manage to do it.